# Safely reading a multilayered GenericRecord in Scala with Option

Tags: scala

I have a question regarding the Option calls. I have a GenericRecord (i) parsed from a JSON object which from which I want to extract value (see code below):

`Option(i.get("Hours_field").asInstanceOf[GenericRecord].get("Hour").asInstanceOf[Double]).getOrElse(-1.0)`

This work fine for most cases but in a few events "Hours_field" is "null" which results in an error.

This of course could be fixed with an if else statement:

```
if (i.get("Hours_field")==null)
{
-1
}
else
{
Option(i.get("Hours_field").asInstanceOf[GenericRecord].get("Hour").asInstanceOf[Double]).getOrElse(-1.0)
}
```

But some sources said that this was an antipattern in Scala. Does anyone know a better way? The "when" option from this [source](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/option-type) sounds promising, but I cannot get it to work. I also tried the map function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159198/how-to-handle-none-values-in-json) but most likely I am using it wrong.
Could anyone explain to me how I can be done? I am still quite new to Scala so excuse the maybe very obvious question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what kind of API `GenericRecord` has, but probably something like this would be better:

```
import scala.util.Try

final class SafeRecord(val record: Option[GenericRecord]) {

  def get(name: String): SafeRecord = record.flatMap { r =>
    SafeRecord(r.get("name")))
  }

  def getDouble(name: String): Option[Double] = record.flatMap { f =>
    Try(r.get(name).asInstanceOf[Double]).toOption
  }
}
object SafeRecord {

  def apply(record: GenericRecord): SafeRecord =
    new SafeRecord(Option(record))
}
```

Used as:

```
SafeRecord(i).get("Hours_field").getDouble("Hour").getOrElse(-1.0)
```

Normally, one doesn't have to play around with such wrappers, as Scala libraries don't use `null`, nor return an arbitrary `Object`/`Any` to downcast, but apparently this it one of "these" Java API so one has to wrap it up to have some safe API.

You could also just use Options with flatMaps:

```
// I don't know if in your case i can be null
Option(i.get("Hours_field"))
  .flatMap(k => Option(k.get("Hours")))
  .flatMap(d => Try(d.asInstanceOf[Double].toOption))
  .getOrElse(-1.0)
```

or for comprehension

```
val d = for {
  j <- Option(i.get("Hours_field"))
  k <- Option(j.get("Hours"))
  l <- Try(l.asInstanceOf[Double]).toOption
} yield l
d.getOrElse(-1.0)
```

But for such particular APIs quasi-optics or paths could be more readable.

Of course, this issue is already solved if you use Scala libraries for JSON, because they can have decoders/encoders generated for you or allow using JSON optics/paths.